# CLion: Show compile-time evaluated value?

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, clion

In Visual Studio it is possible to see compile-time evaluated constexpr values by hovering a mouse over the arguement. For instance, it will show you the value of `sizeof(void*)`. 
However, CLion seems to lack such a feature. If it is so, I am rather disappointed.

Do I miss something? Can it be enabled or how can one see the evaluated compile-time expressions in CLion?

Comment: It's no possible unfortunately. But you can vote/comment [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5064)